# Not sure why I'm getting a segfault in Java/Android when declaring an array

Tags: java, android, memory, segmentation-fault

So I've got some code that is crashing in Android, and I have no idea why.

```
while(true)
{
    byte[] colorData = new byte[480*800];
    colorData = null;
    System.out.println("what");
}
```

It prints out "what" three times, then crashes with "Fatal Signal 11 SIGSEGV" (as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PpRl.png). It is definitely running garbage collection, so the issue doesn't seem to be memory running out, but if I lower the size of the array, it takes longer to crash.

If I remove the colorData lines, then the code works and does not crash. I'm very confused. It could be some of the other code, but I can't understand why adding/removing an array declaration would cause the program to crash/not crash.

Any ideas?

Edit:

So when I force the program to run out of memory by upping my byte array size, I get an out of memory exception. What the hell is causing this segfault?

Comment: you're running this block of code forever "while (true)", and the memory will exceed.

Comment: Creating millions of objects on a memory constrained platform is really just not a good idea.

Comment: Its running 3 times and crashing, so I wouldn't consider it as "creating millions of objects." As you can see from the imgur link I posted, it seems to be running garbage collection, and has plenty of memory free (over a megabyte) to allocate a 400k block. It should be GCing them between iterations as well, and it seems to be doing so, yet it still is crashing.

Comment: Also, when I remove the array allocation, it still crashes when I add System.gc(), it fails with the same error. That makes no sense

Comment: The DVM should not segfault, ever.  It certainly shouldn't segfault because it runs out of memory.  ... and it shouldn't run out of memory  allocating and de-allocating an array.  ... and it certainly shouldn't do it after allocating and dealocating 3 times.  Please have a look at the core dump, if you can catch it, as M Vladmirov describes below.  It would be interesting to know what's going on here.

Comment: I just tried this with a "for" loop, instead of a "while".  It ran for 10000 iterations on an emulator running 4.2

Comment: Hi Jdban101, I have a similar problem which is hard to pinpoint - I also get SIGSEGV and not OutOfMemory. Have you managed to find solution or at least a cause?

Answer (score 1):

Java usually generates crash log file on SIGSEGV.  Also .core file is generated on *nix systems.  These files may be used to know stack trace of where it crashed which many lead to problem source.

Your code works fine for me (64-bit JDK 1.7.0_13 on Windows 7).  It should not exhaust memory because allocated byte arrays become unreferenced at the very next iteration of the loop and will be collected by GC.

Anyway, you need to provide more info, if you want people to help you.  Include at least the following: java version (run "java -version"), OS version (run "ver" on Windows or "uname -a" on *nix), crash log file generated by JVM, complete source of what you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding System.gc() after you set colorData=null. This should force to deallocate the object.

Comment: So interesting thing about trying that. The program still crashed after a couple iterations with System.gc() in there, even if I removed the colorData array... No idea why...

Comment: So even if I'm not allocating stuff, it still crashes when I force garbage collection (same error)

Comment: Nonesense.  If the DVM needs memory it will run the GC.  Calling System.gc() is a no-op.